# Javascript OO key value pair accessor

Tags: javascript, oop

Having trouble accessing a keyvalue pair inside an JS object, getting the following error in chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
>   jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.0.js:4371
>   jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle

So, here is my code:

```
//Separate file named Product.js

function Product() {

    var field = {
        ProductName: "False Teeth",
        SupplierID: 7,
    }

    this.init = function () {
        //any initialisation code
    }

    var getProperty = function (propertyName) {
        return field[propertyName];
    }
};


//In another javascript file, trying to access the object

var product = new Product();

//THIS GIVES THE ERROR undefined is not a function
console.log("supplierID:" + product.getProperty("SupplierID"));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because you made `getProperty()` *private*. Just add `this.`(like you done on `init()`) to it to become *public*.

Comment: Hi, just tried this and it gives me the value of 0, not the stored value I expected of 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
//Separate file named Product.js

function Product() {

    var field = {
        ProductName: "False Teeth",
        SupplierID: 7,
    }

    this.init = function () {
        //any initialisation code
    }

    this.getProperty = function (propertyName) {
        return field[propertyName];
    }
};


//In another javascript file, trying to access the object

var product = new Product();

//THIS GIVES THE ERROR undefined is not a function
console.log("supplierID:" + product.getProperty("SupplierID"));
```

Comment: Still gives me a 0, instead of expected 7?

Comment: Just copy & paste the code. Either your JavaScript engine is buggy or you haven't updated your source code :-).

Comment: The main difference @MinkoGechev introduced was making `getProperty` a member of the `this` object: `this.getProperty = function(propertyName) ...`

Comment: Thanks, you were correct. Well done